# How to install dependencies for Popcorn?

Tags: 18.04, dependencies

I succesfully installed Popcorn but failed to install dependecies with the following line:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libgconf-2-4 libatomic1`

When i type that, I constantly get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOIZI.png

Is there any solution to this problem?

tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove [the PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-mate-dev/+archive/ubuntu/xenial-mate), which does not provide packages for Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS (your current version) with:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:ubuntu-mate-dev/xenial-mate
```

and then retry with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module libgconf-2-4 libatomic1
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much !!! <3

Comment: Now I can start it, but it buffers constantly. When I started it from terminal, it says (sreenshot on IMGUR):      https://i.imgur.com/7rXaSIz.png

Comment: Personally I have never used the Popcorn-Time application. It may be network or GPU issue of Node.js.